# CSS Selector on Responsive Email template

Tags: email, responsive-design

I am currently studying on Responsive Email template. I saw some of the templates online using Attribute Selector like this: ***h1[class="title"]***. Why don't just just ***h1.title***, is there any special trick for doing Email template like this?

Comment: i think i doesn't make any sense to select like this ans its just looks like developer choice see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=6109510#6109510

Comment: It seems that h1[class="title"] apply to exactly one class name, am I right? So if h1 has two class, h1[class="title"] doesn't work.

Comment: @benone rather cheak http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6109898#6109898

Comment: Attribute selectors are being used to avoid an unusual glitch in Yahoo! Mail. from http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/coding/

Answer (score 2):

This trick is done to stop some email clients from recognizing this tag. The most common use of this would be to hide tags that are only used in a mobile version of this email.

For instance the Yahoo.com email client, does not recognize media types or css using the bracketed format. So by using this format you can trick Yahoo mail to not parse css specifically used for the mobile version.